# Activity stops when call comes

Tags: java, android, android-activity, verification

I am developing an application in which My idea is when someone installs the application the user will get a call from a number which is generated randomly, then the application will check if the user gets the call from a particular number only then the user will be able  to go to the next activity.

But my problem,is when the call comes the activity stops and when user opens application again he gets call from new random number

How can I implement this thing any idea?

My Code flow is as in the following manner

```
   getnumber() {
    //getting number from user 
    verifynumber();
}
verifynumber(); {
    //generating random number 
    //here code to call user by random number  
    checkcalllog(); //activity stops as call comes and do not reach at this line
}
checkcalllog() {
    //checking in call log provide if any entry by random number present after call
}
```

Can i do something so that verifynumber() calls checkcalllog() after disconnecting the call? OR something else.

Comment: remove the **;** from **verifynumber();** on 5th line of your question.

Comment: It's just a pseudo code, so doesn't really matter. Anyway, why don't you simply put the random number as a SharedPreference variable and check it the next time the app is started?

Comment: call `checkCallLog` in `onResume` of your activity.

Comment: thank a lot to all of you for giving number of solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option you have is to set up a Service in the background that monitors the call state.  This service should implement a PhoneStateListener, the [onCallStateChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html#onCallStateChanged%28int,%20java.lang.String%29) method will tell you the incoming number.  Be sure to register it with the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29).  When your Activity stops because of the call, when you resume it, you can have it check with your service whether a call was received.

Answer (score 0):

when the call comes the activity stops ie it is moved to background so put checkcalllog(); in your onPause method and have a variable to check whether the number matched set it in your onPause(), once the call disconnects the activty comes back to foreground so in your onResume check the variable and start the activity you want. Tell me if this worked